# Conditionally updating / deleting a document in backend. Should I? Do I assign a PUT, POST, or DELETE http method?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, mongoose

The below function is for a "collection model".

Given certain conditions, I want to either delete or update the document.

Should I use a PUT or DELETE?

I could separate them and check validation / conditions on the client, but that seems less DRY.

I'll have to add additional lines of code to both the client and server to achieve the same thing.

```
CollectionSchema.statics.kill = function(o, cb) {
      return Collection
        .findAsync(o)
        .then(function(existing) {
          if (existing.length && (existing[0].vote !== 0 || existing[0].favorite == true)) {
            return Collection
              .findByIdAndUpdate(o, {
                collected: !existing[0].collected
              }, {
                new: true
              })
              .then(function(updated) {
                console.log('updated ', updated)
                return updated;
              }).catch(function(err) {
                return err;
              })
          } else if (existing.length && existing[0].vote == 0 && existing[0].favorite == false) {
            return Collection
              .removeAsync({
                _id: existing[0]._id
              })
              .then(function(deleted) {
                return {
                  message: 'deleted collection'
                }
              }).catch(function(err) {
                return err;
              })
          }
        }).catch(function(err) {
          return err;
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best option would be to use the simple REST model (a `PUT` to update the document and a `DELETE` to remove the document).

Then, from your client, you call either the update or the remove method depending on your conditions, as you say. To improve this concept, you can send a negative response to the client concerning the `DELETE` event if the document can't be removed.

Comment: Probably so, it just seems like a less DRY way.

Comment: You have to choose between DRY and KISS in some cases, I mainly prefer KISS, but that's a point of view.